# I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)

Tags: r, tensorflow

I am trying to using deep learning in R and when I run this code

```
for(i in 1:Epochs ){
  model %>% fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1, shuffle=FALSE)
  model %>% reset_states()
}
```

I receive the following error

```
2021-04-18 20:12:09.671263: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: in user code:

    /Users/my_user/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /Users/my_user/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /Users/my_user/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /Users/my_user/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /Users/my_user/Library/r-mini
```

What this it mean exactly? `X_train` and `y_train` are both arrays. What is this MLIR thing?